# Safari reuses already existing tabs instead of opening new ones

Tags: safari, tabs

If I click a link in say an e-mail or application and that exact link already has an open tab, Safari will focus that tab instead of opening it anew at the end of the current window.

I would prefer this behaviour to be different because moving the focus is really distracting and often I want the new tab to open in the current window/context.

Is there a way to change this?

Comment: Right click on the link and select "Open in new tab".

Answer (score 0):

In Safari Preferences -> Tabs -> Check the box for "⌘-click opens a link in a new tab".  Then use ⌘-click to force it to open a new tab in Safari when clicking the same URL domain.

Comment: That setting is checked and in that case it keeps opening new tabs. I think this behaviour is when being called from the outside.